# how to change wordpress showposts in each page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way that I can change showposts in each page?
Something like 6 posts in first page of some category, and then you click on next page, and there is 4 posts.

I'm creating a website for kind of magazine, an I want to posts count in each category be as same as the articles in magazine's section. (the mag has 6 sections and so my website has 6 category).
If you get that, I want that when we click on next page, it show's the articles from previous magazine number.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the Each category a page. Just open each category in a new window. Take that URL and assign it to a menu item in your navigation.

All you'll have to do after that is style your Category page template.php